# Multi Authority Attribute Based Encryption Library

Tags: abe

Anyone aware of a library that has MA-ABE implemented in any language preferably python?

P/S - I hope this is the right place to ask this. Apologies if not, then a redirect will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Charm crypto](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm), a Python framework, contains three multi-authority schemes. Two of them were contributed by me: [1](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/blob/dev/charm/schemes/abenc/abenc_dacmacs_yj14.py) & [2](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/blob/dev/charm/schemes/abenc/abenc_maabe_yj14.py) and another [one](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/blob/dev/charm/schemes/dabe_aw11.py) was already included.

Yannis Rouselakis also has a [MA-ABE implementation](https://sites.google.com/site/yannisrouselakis/rwabe) in Charm on his site.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the links. I need to explore the Charm library more as that is what I will be using to implement.

Comment: Also I noticed that the MA-ABE implementations are CP-ABE based, is there any for KP-ABE? May have to try and implement that myself then :)